# Save some values before button PostBack

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback

Well I've got some textboxes dinamically created in a .cs file and I want to save/store their values when I click on Update button in a detailsview's edit mode, so I've got seted button's onclick event to a function to do this.

The problem is that the postback event occurs before the "OnClick" event, and then the textboxes' values are lost.

How can I save/store their values first?.

Please, help me with this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You mean, the postback (on the client) happens before the 'OnClick' happens (on the server), sounds right.

Answer (score 0):

You can detect the page's first loading or post back(OnClick, SelectedItemIndexChanged like..) with the Page.IsPostBack property.
You should check this property value in the Page_Laoad event handler.

Comment: Hi user565002, Yes, but in that moment my values are lost and I cannot access to them anymore, that's why I want to store them before Page_Load executes

Comment: OK, if your control created dynamically you should save value in the ViewState object http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/502251/How-to-create-controls-dynamically-in-ASP-NET-and

Comment: Thanks user565002, I'll take a deeper look to that article. It looks interesting. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It helps to understand the ASP.NET page life cycle.(See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) for more info.)
Basic events are as follows:

- PreInit
- Init
- PreLoad
- Load (controls are filled with postback values here)
- Control events (OnClick happens here)
- PreRender
- Render
- Unload

Usually during the "Init" event you want to create all of the controls, including any dynamic controls for the user.

During the Load event asp.net copies all of the post date back from the client to the controls in the page.  But in order for this to work on the postback the same controls that were created on the initial render must exist in the same order with the same IDs.

Then in PreRender you can change the page state including adding  and removing controls for the next post.

So to clarify here's how I would imagine your page flow:

- OnInit - Construct your controls and populate with the initial values.
- OnLoad - During postback your control will be populated with the users updated values.
- OnClick - Use the event of the user's button click to then save the updated values.

Comment: Thanks for your answer John, so imagine that I press a button and page events begins in the order you said in your list. Should I call the function for create dynamic controls in the INI event? And if so, in which event could I get the "before button click" values for the dynamic controls?

Comment: Add a listener to the Click event of the button control.  Then you can look at the values of all of the controls at that time.

Comment: Do you mean "OnClick"? This executes after PostBack if I'm not wrong

Comment: Yes OnClick.  So you should have the values that were entered by the user.  I've updated my answer to clarify the parts of the page flow relevant for this question.